# SQL database - changing a part of the text content of an attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have created several products in a database and saw now that by copying very unattractive names in the attribute art_nr have arisen. Does anyone know how I can search for all these attributes using a SQL query and then, for example, at the first 001-PT1000-new-new-new-new change the text automatically to 001-PT1000? Say it should cut away the last part of the text.

I have already managed the search for all elements that contain a new in the name.

Would be very happy if someone here knows a code approach.

Best regards

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5a47.jpg)

Comment: You must provide a sample (simplified CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, remove unnesessary columns) with some (the best way - all) incorrect values (and some correct - this may help), and show desired final data state. Also specify precise MySQL version. PS. Pictures are not useful.

Comment: Andreas, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read why you shouldn't post unnecessary [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). One question, how you think that anyone can read anything from your picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the part of the string before the first occurrence of `'-new'`:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET art_nr = SUBSTRING_INDEX(art_nr, '-new', 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

> at the first `001-PT1000-new-new-new-new` change the text automatically to `001-PT1000`

```
UPDATE tablename
SET art_nr = TRIM(TRAILING '-new' FROM art_nr);
```

Comment: Unlike in other databases, MySQL's trims treat the removal strings as a unit, not just a collection of characters.  So this does exactly what the OP is asking for.